# How to concatenate 3 arrays from files after a foreach loop?

Tags: php

Can you please tell me how to merge several arrays into one using the array_merge () function after the foreach loop? I write this function:

```
public function getFilesGenres() {
    $files = scandir(__DIR__.'/genres');
    $config = config('songscrud.genres.langs');

    $array = [];
    foreach($config as $lang) {
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            if(preg_match('/\.(php)/', $file))
            {
                $path = __DIR__.'/genres/' . $file;
                $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

                if ($lang === $ext) {
                    $array[$lang] = require($path);
                    $array = array_merge($array[$lang]);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return $array;
}
```

I write each array into an array with a language like en, ru, de. As a result, it produces only an array from the first file and nothing is combined. I tried to write like this:

```
$array1 = ['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => NULL, 'lft' => NULL, 'rgt' => NULL, 'depth' => 1, 'name_ru' => 'Народная музыка', 'slug_ru' => 'народная-музыка', 'translit_ru' => 'narodnaja-muzyka'];
$array2 = ['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => NULL, 'lft' => NULL, 'rgt' => NULL, 'depth' => 1, 'name_de' => 'Ethnische Musik', 'slug_de' => 'ethnische-musik'];
$array3 = ['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => NULL, 'lft' => NULL, 'rgt' => NULL, 'depth' => 1, 'name_en' => 'Ethnic music', 'slug_en' => 'ethnic-music'];

return array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

This code works well and combines everything into one array. How to concatenate arrays dynamically through files with arrays using a loop?

Comment: it's because you are using the same variable name to get the file array and then merge and save it to the new array (having same name). do like this: `if ($lang === $ext) {
                    $data[$lang] = require($path);
                    $array = array_merge($data[$lang]);
                }`

Comment: That regex is not explicitly checking the end of the filename.

Comment: And this is at least confusing `$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);` or maybe wrong !!